# Calculate total number of threads in the operating system(Windows/Linux)

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

How to calculate and display a total number of threads in the operating system using C#/LINQ, 
basically looking for something like this:

```
var query = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
       select new
       {
         count = sum(p.Threads.Count)
       };
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads ?

Comment: Not sure what you are actually looking for, but a little warning, the current answers give the threads that are currently created eg. TheGeneral's answer outputs on my machine 3347 threads, but that number is no where near the number the OS could potentielly run at the same time. So if I where to check the `ThreadState == ThreadState.Running` I would only get 9 as a result. The second answer by vivek nuna limits the query to the `CurrentProcess` only so you would only get a number representing the threads you have created in your own process, again no matter if the are running or not.

Comment: Here the query to check the `ThreadState` - `var runningCount = Process.GetProcesses().SelectMany(x => x.Threads.OfType<ProcessThread>()).Count(x => x.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running);`

Comment: @RandRandom I think, you should post your code as an answer:)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - as I said "Not sure what you are actually looking for" so I have no idea what OP wants, so I don't feel comfortable giving an answer to a question that IMHO isn't clear

Comment: Intention was to understand number of current existed threads in the system in use by all processes. It seems that your query is only addresses current process.

Comment: @Genady - where you commenting to me?

Comment: Please use @Username so the user gets a ping about your comment

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
var count = Process.GetProcesses().Sum(p => p.Threads.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get by below method also.

```
int count = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;
```

Comment: Intention was to understand number of current existed threads in the system in use by all processes. It seems that your query is only addresses a current process